# Error after updating androidx.appcompat:appcompat

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-appcompat

Error after updating `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` to version `1.5.0`

Error:

```
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy found in modules lifecycle-viewmodel-2.5.0-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.5.0) and lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.3.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewTreeViewModelKt found in modules lifecycle-viewmodel-2.5.0-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.5.0) and lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.3.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 32
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ewrqgbwer.android"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.1.4.4"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

    packagingOptions {
        resources.excludes.add("META-INF/*")
    }

}

dependencies {

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.1.0')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.2.12'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:20.1.2'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'

    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I rummaged through all the libraries and the problem turned out to be an outdated version of `com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.1.0`.